# Displaying the Go back in line in php

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

I have this admin page where you ENter the Products information and description
[ADD/UPDATE category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y99WJ.png)

And even If I go back in line in the description it doesn't show in the manage category section how do I fix that? and if the text is too long it can cause some displaying problems

[Manage Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miywR.png)

Comment: Can you better explain the problem, it is not clear. You have tagged three tangentially related technologies, and I can’t tell where to even start. "In line" almost sounds like a CSS problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.